# XSLT split record in child node but remain Parent content

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a large XML file which having multiple child records in the XML file.
I wanted to split the XML file out for each Child records, but want to keep the parent content without touching that.

Below is the Example of my XML file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<DATA>
    <Account Number='1536764-9'>
        <T1>testing1</T1>
        <T2>testing2</T2>
        <T3>testing3</T3>
        <T4>testing4</T4>
        <Mobile Number='12345'>
            <InvoiceNo>40800844</InvoiceNo>
            <SO_RC>
                <Code>7679</Code>
                <Description>GPS - Fleet Management Service</Description>
                <Amt>268.00</Amt>
                <PeriodFromDate>01/08/2015</PeriodFromDate>
                <PeriodToDate>31/08/2015</PeriodToDate>
            </SO_RC>
            <TotalSubscriber>268.00</TotalSubscriber>
        </Mobile>
        <Mobile Number='22345'>
            <InvoiceNo>40800844</InvoiceNo>
            <SO_RC>
                <Code>7679</Code>
                <Description>GPS - Fleet Management Service</Description>
                <Amt>268.00</Amt>
                <PeriodFromDate>01/08/2015</PeriodFromDate>
                <PeriodToDate>31/08/2015</PeriodToDate>
            </SO_RC>
            <TotalSubscriber>268.00</TotalSubscriber>
        </Mobile>
        <Mobile Number='32345'>
            <InvoiceNo>40800844</InvoiceNo>
            <SO_RC>
                <Code>7679</Code>
                <Description>GPS - Fleet Management Service</Description>
                <Amt>268.00</Amt>
                <PeriodFromDate>01/08/2015</PeriodFromDate>
                <PeriodToDate>31/08/2015</PeriodToDate>
            </SO_RC>
            <TotalSubscriber>268.00</TotalSubscriber>
        </Mobile>
    </Account>
    <Total_Records>212</Total_Records>
    <Total_Outstanding_Balance>0.00</Total_Outstanding_Balance>
    <Total_Current_Bill_Amt>0.00</Total_Current_Bill_Amt>
</DATA>
```

I have some script like below, able to split out the child but without copying the Parent Content like below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/> 
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="DATA/Account/Mobile">
         <xsl:result-document href="file:///{encode-for-uri('{WATCHTEMPFOLDER}')}{format-number(position(),'000000000')}.xml">
          <DATA>
          <Account>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
          </Account>
          </DATA>
         </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>  
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This code able to split out my Child content with copying all the Mobile tag info. But I am not getting any Parent content in the new XML. The result of my code are showing as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA>
    <Account>
        <Mobile Number="62087704">
            <InvoiceNo>40800844</InvoiceNo>
            <SO_RC>
                <Code>7679</Code>
                <Description>GPS - Fleet Management Service</Description>
                <Amt>268.00</Amt>
                <PeriodFromDate>01/08/2015</PeriodFromDate>
                <PeriodToDate>31/08/2015</PeriodToDate>
            </SO_RC>
            <TotalSubscriber>268.00</TotalSubscriber>
        </Mobile>
    </Account>
</DATA>
```

I am not that good in XSLT, but wish to have some advice or comment how could I achieve the desired XML file (as below).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<DATA>
    <Account Number='1536764-9'>
        <T1>testing1</T1>
        <T2>testing2</T2>
        <T3>testing3</T3>
        <T4>testing4</T4>
        <Mobile Number='32345'>
            <InvoiceNo>40800844</InvoiceNo>
            <SO_RC>
                <Code>7679</Code>
                <Description>GPS - Fleet Management Service</Description>
                <Amt>268.00</Amt>
                <PeriodFromDate>01/08/2015</PeriodFromDate>
                <PeriodToDate>31/08/2015</PeriodToDate>
            </SO_RC>
            <TotalSubscriber>268.00</TotalSubscriber>
        </Mobile>
    </Account>
    <Total_Records>212</Total_Records>
    <Total_Outstanding_Balance>0.00</Total_Outstanding_Balance>
    <Total_Current_Bill_Amt>0.00</Total_Current_Bill_Amt>
</DATA>
```

Comment: Could you also explain why you want to split the file this way?

Comment: Hi Tomalak, cause of the original design of this XML file come in with very large amount of mobile number data. And this cause my software very difficult to run over the data. I would need to split into smaller record for processing.

Comment: Consider changing your software to use a SAX parser. These can handle large XML files better than DOM parsers. Depending on what you do, exactly, that could be a more sensible approach than splitting your file.

Comment: @Tomalak, splitting a large XML file into multiple smaller files is often much more convenient than writing a SAX application. SAX is hard, and we shouldn't recommend it to people unless we are very sure they have enough programming experience - we see an awful lot of people here getting themselves into a muddle with SAX. And in any case, he's not using a DOM parser, he's using XSLT.

Comment: @MichaelKay He's using XSLT because his main application (which is using a DOM parser, I presume) struggles with the XML and he seeks a way to make it more manageable. Recommending to at least look at SAX isn't too far out in this situation.

Comment: @Tomalak You appear to have inside knowledge of the application that wasn't revealed in the question.

Comment: @MichaelKay No, I was making an educated guess. I fully take your point, SAX has the potential to make things worse. That's why I worded my comment as a cautious suggestion ("Consider", "Depending on what you do, exactly").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  version="2.0"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs xsi">

<xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:param name="base-dir" select="'C:\What-ever-directory\'" /> 

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="DATA/Account/Mobile" />
  <empty xsi:nil="true" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Mobile">
  <xsl:variable name="doc-no" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:number format="000000001" level="any" />
  </xsl:variable>   
  <xsl:variable name="href" select="concat('file:///', encode-for-uri( concat( $base-dir, $doc-no)),'.xml')" />
  <xsl:result-document href="{$href}" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/*" mode="mini-doc">
    <xsl:with-param name="Mobile" tunnel="yes" select="." />
  </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="mini-doc">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="mini-doc"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Mobile" mode="mini-doc">
  <xsl:param name="Mobile" tunnel="yes" />
  <xsl:if test=". is $Mobile">
    <xsl:next-match />
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The main output document is nil, but if that is not what you want, then just replace the sequence constructor for nil with `xsl:copy-of`. Pass in the base directory as a parameter to this stylesheet, with parameter name `base-dir`.

Comment: Hi Sean, Thanks a lot that's work!!
By the way, was wonder is it possible to split it base on 2 children node?
Or if I want exclude some of the children node content in it?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Sure. To exclude some of the child document content, add templates with mode `mini-doc`. If by "split it base on 2 children", you mean put two Mobile elements per mini-doc, use a for-each-group instruction to pair them up and pass the sequence of two as a tunneling parameter. Change the if test accordingly.